# Is logging a valid non-functional requirement?

Tags: logging, non-functional

Working in an architecture roles I was asking the team that was developing a component to add some logging at certain points. For this I was offered and NFR document to fill in.

Does logging fit as a Non functional Requirement or could they go somewhere else. in oneway a NFR document is convienent for a boiler plate requirement but its functional in that actions trigger logs.

Comment: I can see it both ways.  While I think it's a functional requirement, in that it actually specifies *functionality*, that functionality does not contribute directly to any user story or use case.

Comment: To add to the comment by @RobertHarvey, it can be seen as a non-functional requirement because it is something that needs to be kept in mind for every future story you implement (i.e. it probably ends up in the definition-of-done).

Answer (score 7):

That depends on the scope of your application. If you have some legal liability to provide a thorough logging of calculations, user-interactions with the software etc, you need the logging to fulfill your functional requirements.

On the other hand, if you're talking about logging to provide your developers, sysadmins and/or operations a means of debugging and monitoring, then it may not be an actual requirement. In that case, you will have a somewhat *pure* non-functional requirement.

Comment: Was the pun in "pure non-functional" requirement intended?

Comment: As I have to ask you 'what pun' - nope. ;)

Comment: I thought it was a twist on "pure" and "functional" as in "purely functional programming language".